# Sequence of integrable functions that converge a.e but not their integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to find an example of a sequence of integrable functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_n\rightarrow 0$ a.e. (almost everywhere) but $\int f_n\nrightarrow 0$. Should be easy, but I can't think of any examples.

Comment: The result is true if there is a dominating function. So try to think up a sequence $\{f_n\}$ which cannot be bounded above by an integrable function.

Comment: What about $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there is an example:

In $(\mathbf{R},\mathscr{B(\mathbf{R})},\lambda)$, where $\lambda(dx)=dx$ is the Lebesgue measure. Consider the sequence of functions
$$
f_n(x):=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x),
$$
then $f_n\to f$ $(n\to\infty)$, where $f\equiv0$. But $\int_\mathbf{R}f_n(x)dx=n\cdot\frac{1}{n}\equiv1$ for all $n$, not converges to $0$.